# using matlab to solve plotting function

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I've been asked to plot the function
f(*x*) = (*x*^2 - 3x + 7) / (sqrt(2x +5))

for -1< *x* <5

how would I go about starting this?

Thanks all

Comment: `f = @(x) (x^2 - 3*x + 7)/(sqrt(2*x +5))` - the rest is really up to you for trying. Tell us where you get stuck and show us the code you already have ;)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask carefully, especially the "Search, and research" part.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab works with arrays (matrices actually). First, you need to create an array with the `x` values:

```
x = -1: 0.01: 5
```

where `0.01` is the interval between consecutive values.

Then you need to calculate to `y` values.

```
y = (x.^2 - 3*x + 7) ./ (sqrt(2*x + 5));
```

This is quite straightforward. The only thing you need to notice is the dots. The `.*`, `./` operators work element-wise (which you need, since you want to calculate the square of the values). If instead you typed `x^2`, it would mean matrix multiplication of `x` by itself, which would produce the wrong values in your case.
Finally, to plot it:

```
plot(x, y, '.b');
```

`x` and `y` are obvious. The last part refers to the color and style of the line. In this case it mean blue dots. For other styles see [Matlab line styles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html).

Comment: It is also possible to use matlabs **symbolic math toolbox**. Then matlab does all evaluation using symbolic maths. Then the function can be plotted using `ezplot`. *@reto* +1 for pointing out proper way of asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can, also, do this by using the symbolic toolbox as follows:

```
syms x
y = (x^2 - 3*x + 7)/(sqrt(2*x+5));
figure
ezplot(y,[-1,5]) % -1 is the xmin and 5 the xmax
```

update: I just noticed that patrick mentioned the usage of symbolic toolbox, but it worths seeing the code as a whole